# Error: _lib_getAllUsers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, next.js

I am following the Next.js series by [Dave Gray](https://www.youtube.com/@DaveGrayTeachesCode) on YouTube.

I am trying to import a function from **"lib/getAllUsers"**

[image]

I get the error

```js
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: _lib_getAllUsers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function
```

**Expected Behavior**: I am trying to fetch users information from `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself.

Use an arrow function in `lib/getAllUsers`

```js
// lib/getAllUsers

export const getAllUsers = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");

    if(!res.ok) throw new Error("failed to fetch data")

    return res.json();
}
```

Import the function where you want to use it. `app/users/page.tsx`

```js
// app/users/page.tsx

import {getAllUsers} from '@/lib/getAllUsers'
```

**Next.js version 13.2.4**

**Node.js version 18.15.0**